# Function in "when clause" seems to get cached

Tags: java, drools, rule

I have a usecase where I need to implement a counter, which basically resets every minute. It's in a java class called Counter, where I use two methods :

- addDate() which adds a date to the list
- getSize() which CLEARS all dates that are older than one minute and returns the size of the new list

Now the addDate() is used in my "then" clause, where I do some treatment, while the getSize() is used in the "when" clause. Point being, I shouldn't do the treatment if I already did N treatments in the last minute.

The rule looks like this :

```
rule "AffWebService"
when
    $compteur : Counter(getSize() < max.intValue())
then
    // treatment
    modify ( $compteur ) { addDate() };
```

end

Basically it works until the list's size is equal to max (which is a Drools global). I added a logger in the getSize() function that gets triggered everytime, so that's nice.

Now, the tricky part. Once the list's size equals the max, the getSize() doesn't even get triggered anymore (which is problematic, since it's the same function that clears the "old dates"). It's like Drools "cached" the value and doesn't execute it, maybe until I modify the Counter ?

By the way, the Counter is a fact that I inserted inside a rule that gets triggered only once at the start of the session.

Any hints appreciated... thanks !

Comment: The rule you have posted will quickly add items to the list until max is reached by immediately firing again and again. I don't see what this should achieve. Perhaps you tell us what really should happen and from where new items are added, and when and how and why.

Comment: Well, basically I need to make calls to a Webservice and drools is supposed to help us "not overload" the distant server. What I need to do is regulate the flow, for example not more than 50 calls in a minute. The facts get added by a Java-based application server, so basically everytime a new fact comes in, I need to check if I already did 50 calls in the last minute, if not, it can get treated. The getSize() does clear the dates in the last that are older than one minute, to ensure that the counter is updated.

Comment: Basically after some more testing, once the condition has been FALSE one time, the rule never gets triggered again even tough the value returned from getSize() would be different some time after. Fwiw I use the same session and retract every fact (but my Counter) after firing all rules. Any clues ?

Comment: I tried adding a rule that updates the counter when it reaches max value. Either it loops over and over again, or if I add the no-loop it just triggers once and never again. Is there a way to trigger a rule each time a new Fact is added to the working memory, whatever the type of that fact is ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the second bulletpoint in your question, where you stated:

> getSize() which CLEARS all dates that are older than one minute and returns the size of the new list

clearly highlight a warning/anti-pattern [as mentioned in the Drools docs](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.4.0.Final/drools-docs/html/ch08.html#d0e9325):

> Property accessors must not change the state of the object in a way that may effect the rules. Remember that the rule engine effectively caches the results of its matching in between invocations to make it faster.

So my suggestion would be to refactor the Counter and the rule definitions, to avoid this problem and comply with the documentation; for instance, have another separate rule to trigger the "old dates" removal and *modify* a Counter, or *modify* a dedicated Counter "size" field - both in the RHS of such separate rule.

(I've assumed Drools version 6.4.0.Final)